# WindowsFormsHost inside ViewBox or How do I rescale WindowsFormsHost content?

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize, viewbox, windowsformshost

I have a really complex setup here. Somewhere in my code I have a `WindowsFormsHost` and the content (Child) of it is set to what comes out of a DLL. I only give a bitmap to a dll and say: Give me the `UserControl` (Windows.Forms) and put it inside my `WindowsFormsHost`.
After that, everything works fine as intended, except that I cannot resize the `Window` and the content resizes with it. Normally I would use a `ViewBox` for it, but I guess, because the `WindowsFormsHost` is drawn by `GDI+`, it ignores the auto resizing of the `ViewBox`.

If that is true, I could use a completely different approach. I already tried it with a `DockPanel` but couldn't get it to work. It seems as would the `WindowsFormsHost` itself resize but the content of it stays at the same size as it was drawn initially.

Has someone an idea?

Important parts of the code:
Window:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentControl Name="ContentUserControl" Content="{Binding DifferentControl}"
                DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}" />
    </Border>
</Viewbox>
```

UserControl:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="FormsHost" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
mMyWindow.MyUserControl.FormsHost.Child = new ImageControl(externalDllInstance);
```

ImageControl:

```
public class ImageControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    ... normal constructor, an override for the OnPaint and few more properties, nothing important.
    ... The external dll (written in C++) instance does the rest.
    ... It is some kind of black box to me, but could be changed if it would help.
}
```